# AS3 Carousel Buttons Next/Prev Frame Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've got a simple set of banners with 3/4 frames, i've got the next/prev frame working up until the first or last frame where i'd like it to skip to the first or last frame should you reach the "end".

Can't figure out how to do it however!

Current code is:

```
stop();
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

prevBtn.addEventListener(
    MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,
    function(evt:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("prev frame");
        prevFrame();
    }
);

nextBtn.addEventListener(
    MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,
    function(evt:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("next frame");
        nextFrame();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a conditional for what to do if you're at the first or last frame.

```
prevBtn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, doPrev );
nextBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, doNext);

function doPrev(evt:MouseEvent) {
    if (currentFrame > 1) {
        trace("prev frame");
        prevFrame();
    }
    else {
        gotoAndStop(totalFrames);
    }
}

function doNext(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("clicked nextBtn. currentFrame: "+currentFrame);
    if (currentFrame<totalFrames) {
        trace("next frame");
        nextFrame();
    }
    else {
        gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

New to the AS3 game what is the thisMC bit? I should probably have said theyre currently buttons!

Comment: I removed the thisMC bit, that's my habit for keeping scope of the timeline, but not used here. I changed your anonymous function, not sure why that style gives me problems.